# Partitions and divisor functions: what is known about their relations?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

If $i\geq 1$ is an integer, we have the following integer valued functions (for any integer $n\geq 0$):

\begin{align}
p_i(n)&=\textrm{the number of }i\textrm{-dimensional partitions of }n,\notag\\
\sigma_i(n)&=\sum_{d|n}d^i.
\end{align}

If $i=1$, $p_1(n)=p(n)$ is the number of "usual" [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$ (corresponding to decompositions of $n$ as a sum of natural numbers; these also correspond to Young tableaux). If $i=2$, we get the so-called [plane partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition). These generalize for higher $i$'s.

Now, for $i=1,2$ there is a formula relating $p_i$ and $\sigma_i$, namely
$$np_i(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma_i(k)p_i(n-k).$$

> My question is purely a reference request: is it known whether there
>   is an analogous formula for $i>2$?

I would not be surprised if this was not known, because few is known about higher dimensional partitions. Up to the plane ones, we know the generating function (but no closed formula for $p_i(n)$, for *any* $i$). For $i>2$, we do not even know the generating function.

Thank you!

EDIT. References for the recursive formulas: [$i=1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) (formula 13)  and [$i=2$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html) (formula 6). (The case $i=1$ is somehow more classical, and the result can be found also in textbooks.)

Comment: Can you supply a reference for the $i=1,2$ formulas?

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, thanks. When I chased through the references, I found proofs (or sketches) of the recursive formulas - all of them started with the generating function and then proved the recurrence from there. That makes me pessimistic about finding similar formulas for higher-dimensional partitions. Do you know of any combinatorial (bijective) proofs of the recurrences for $i=1,2$? - that might be the only hope left for generalizing to higher dimensions.

Comment: I agree with your comment, I am a bit pessimistic for the same reason. Btw, I read somewhere that Erdős gave a proof for $i=1$ without using the generating function. But I miss the precise reference. As for $i=2$, unfortunately I am not aware of any combinatorial proof...